# Pelican drivers error

Tags: ros, pelican

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to install asctec drivers on workstation, both asctec_drivers and mav_tools folders (package) are in workspace. After command ‘rosmake mav_tools’,I get following errors:

---

[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['mav_tools']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/roboticslab/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121022-094533
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['mav_tools'] to:
['mav_common', 'city_flyer_launch', 'mav_srvs', 'quad_joy_teleop', 'ab_filter', 'mav_odom_interface', 'flyer_interface', 'laser_height_estimation', 'mav_msgs', 'mav_ctrl_interface']

[ rosmake ] Checking rosdeps compliance for packages mav_tools.  This may take a few seconds.

Failed to find stack for package [navfn]
Failed to load rosdep.yaml for package [navfn]:Cannot locate installation of package navfn: [rospack] opendir error [No such file or directory] while crawling /home/roboticslab/Pelican_workspace/astec_drivers
[rospack] couldn't find package [navfn]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/electric/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/roboticslab/Pelican_workspace:/opt/ros/electric/stacks:/home/roboticslab/Pelican_workspace/astec_drivers:/home/roboticslab/Pelican_workspace/mav_tools]

Failed to find stack for package [costmap_2d]
Failed to load rosdep.yaml for package [costmap_2d]:Cannot locate installation of package costmap_2d: [rospack] opendir error [No such file or directory] while crawling /home/roboticslab/Pelican_workspace/astec_drivers
[rospack] couldn't find package [costmap_2d]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/electric/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/roboticslab/Pelican_workspace:/opt/ros/electric/stacks:/home/roboticslab/Pelican_workspace/astec_drivers:/home/roboticslab/Pelican_workspace/mav_tools]
[ rosmake ] rosdep check passed all system dependencies in packages
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> mav_ctrl_interface [ make ]
[ rosmake ] All 23 linesav_ctrl_interface: 0.1 sec ]                                        [ 1 Active 1/53 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]
[rosbuild] Building package mav_ctrl_interface
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/electric/ros/bin/rospack deps-manifests mav_ctrl_interface
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosbuild ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbuild
No Makefile in package rosbuild
[rospack] opendir error [No such file or directory] while crawling /home/roboticslab/Pelican_workspace/astec_drivers
[rospack] couldn't find dependency [navfn] of [mav_ctrl_interface]
[rospack] missing dependency

CMake Error at /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):

```
Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package
'mav_ctrl_interface'.  Look above for errors from rospack itself.
Aborting.  Please fix the broken dependency!
```

Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:206 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)

### -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package mav_ctrl_interface written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/roboticslab/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121022-094533/mav_ctrl_interface/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< mav_ctrl_interface [FAIL] [ 0.17 seconds ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> cpp_common [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< cpp_common ROS_NOBUILD in package cpp_common
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package mav_ctrl_interface.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
No Makefile in package roslang
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 6 packages with 1 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/roboticslab/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121022-094533

---

I am following the steps mentioned on:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/asctec_drivers

http://www.ros.org/wiki/mav_tools

If some one could please suggest any solution, it will be really helpful.
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46428/pelican-drivers-error/) by [dbs](https://answers.ros.org/users/3417/dbs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know if you already had it done, but for those who may get stucked in such a problem, here is my step by step to install mav_tools and asctec_drivers . It worked to me, for **ROS-Groovy**, after a lot of mistakes and helps from this forum. I will start from the beginning:

**First step**, make sure you have GIT installed:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core
```

**Second step**, create a folder where you are going to have other packages from ROS, those you can not install through apt-get... For example:

```
mkdir ~/rospackages
cd ~/rospackages
and download the packages, you can find the links in Ros website. I cant publish links here.
```

**Third step**, you need to indicate where are the ROS packages, now you will have two folders, the original from ROS installation, and the one you have created:

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/rospackages/:/opt/ros/groovy
```

The **:** adds another folder, so if you have another folder to add, just write **:** and the location. It is important that ~/rospackages comes first so, you won't have any problems with read/write problems.

**Fourth step**, now you can do:

```
rosdep install mav_tools
rosmake mav_tools
```

Well, I had two erros after doing rosmake, so it leads to my final steps. If there were no errors after rosmake, ignore the following steps:

**Fifth step**, you may have an error related to the version of rosdep, it is caused due a conflict with the versions installed. So you will need to remove the easy-installed version:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep*
```

Try again `rosmake mav_tools`.

**Sixth step**, you may have a problem related to rosgraph and python-netifaces. Just do the following command:

```
rosdep update
```

Try again `rosmake mav_tools`

After you have done it, just write:

```
rosdep install asctec_drivers
rosmake asctec_drivers
```

---

Originally posted by [Amarante](https://answers.ros.org/users/4583/amarante/) with karma: 31 on 2013-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sendoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/6040/sendoh/) on 2013-08-19**:
Dear Amarante ,

By using "sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep*" , I can not remove the easy-installed version. My rosdep version is 0.9.7. Can you give me further help?

**Comment by [lucasbpro](https://answers.ros.org/users/19022/lucasbpro/) on 2014-06-30**:
I am having the same problem! Can someone help me out?

**Comment by [aly](https://answers.ros.org/users/20349/aly/) on 2014-10-16**:
Hi! I am getting the following error on running first command of 4th step and unable to resolve it:

ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
laser_height_estimation: Missing resource bullet
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros
ROS path